# Patching Exchange2010 without a DC

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2010

This may be a strange problem. I have a primary/standby Exchange 2010 pair. The standby is a clone of the primary after the Exchange installation. The standby is running and connected to the primary through a private NIC. But not to the LAN. Any data wrt Exchange coming in to the primary will be copied to the standby through the private connection. But the Exchange on the standby would not run; the services are switched off. So if I need to switch over, I up the exchange on the standby, down it on primary, change the network cable (of LAN) from primary to standby. It works for me. I have handled all the other implications.

But the problem is with patching the Exchange on the standby server. I can get the patches through the Primary server; no problem. But the installation fails complaining that the server can't see the DC. Does anybody have an idea to work this around?

Is AD LDS worth a try? What I mean here is planting a dummy AD on the standby machine, kicking it off when the server acts as a standby and stopping the AD LDS when the server changes mode to primary. Is it possible to change the AD the exchange points to to the local one? This may make the stand by believe that it could see an AD. But I don't know how to do it. Any thoughts?

The OS is Win 2008 R2.

Comment: Can I ask why you would set it up this way instead of setting up a DAG?

Comment: That's a very long history. All I can say is at this point any other  approach like DAG is not in the pipeline.

Comment: If it's not then it should be, or at least take exchange aware backups of the primary and keep the second server's hardware on standby as backup.

Comment: As I have mentioned, I do not have problems in the data that exchange uses. I only have problem in patching exchange with the new roll ups. So even a DAG can only bring the data back. Am I wrong here? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, this won't work. Exchange is expecting to see *THE* Active Directory database that matches its data and configuration.

Stop doing this now. The amount of time you spend on getting this completely unsupported and dangerous configuration to work will cost you more than purchasing the licensing needed to get a DAG running.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, you're doing it the hard way.

If you can't set up a DAG then at the very least you should be capturing Full backups of the primary Exchange server on a regular basis and using that for disaster recovery.

Comment: Well, the standby server may not necessarily be of the same configuration as the primary one - hardware-wise. As I have mentioned in one of the previous comments data is not the problem here. I have handled it. It is the patching of the standby which is temporarily off the domain.

Comment: If it were me I wouldn't count on your solution actually working. In addition, Windows Server Backup is capable of performing a bare metal restore to dissimilar hardware.

Comment: Thanks @joeqwerty. The backup mainly is data oriented. You schedule a backup may be few times a day, it runs and captures a snapshot at the scheduled time. But in my approach, I replicate live data, ie. whatever that comes into the primary will be mirrored to the standby server. The exchange will be waiting on the standby server to be fired. When the primary is down, the secondary picks up (almost) from where the primary gave up. Hope I have covered much for this comment. I would admit that I might be unaware of such an existing mechanism already. Please advise me if so. Thanks.

Comment: I guess my questions are: Have you actually tested this? Does it actually work? If you perform a failover can users connect to their mailboxes on the secondary server and does mail flow work?

Comment: @user630286 This reeks of something that is not going to work for you.  Are you live copying the log files to the standby server and never cleaning them up?  It doesn't sound like you are doing an exchange aware backup, so are you just keeping all your log files?

Comment: joeqwerty and Cheekaleak, this approach works without any glitch. If I failover the users would not even notice that the exchange is running on the standby. The aim is that; operation without any interruption. This works for ages. Tested up to Exchange 2010. The only problem is the Exchange patching. When in standby mode the patching does not work as the standby server is separated from the LAN. Please let me know if I missed anything in this regard.